# customize modem webinterface

Tags: networking, router, user-interface

I have an old modem

Thomson 510 [enter link description here](http://support.alcadis.nl/files/get_file?file=Technicolor%252FBasic%252FEOL%2B-%2BEnd%2Bof%2BLife%252FST546%252FManuals%252F5x6_manual_cli_en.pdf)

There is tons of functionality that is only available through telnet like firewall rules, logs , dhcp server lease lists, enabling and disabling ethernet interfaces etc.

and I would like to be able to customize the web interface to include some of that functionality.

**is this achievable ? If yes what are areas that I should look into?**

Comment: You will be unable to customize the web interface.  If you want that functionality update your modem to something that already has that functionality

Comment: no I dont need it really , it is just experimenting. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not achievable.

Manufacturer didn't include in its HTTP server such functionalities and there is no way to change its behavior as it is embedded and not programmable.

Comment: how does it serve the customization page on 10.0.0.138 then ?

Comment: I slightly changed my answer.